# materialized views that updates every night

Tags: oracle

Want to create materialized view that updates every night, like:

```
   Create materialized view My_View 
    refresh complete 
    start with (23:00 pm) 
    Next to 24h 
    select....
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: What's the problem? That you can't figure out how to [calculate the right argument for START WITH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm#i2119766), or what?

Comment: Yes, havent worked anything with Oracle or materialzed views before. How can set it to start 23 pm and then wait for 24 h. Sysdate + 24h in seconds?

Comment: Did you follow the link in my comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_view
   REFRESH NEXT SYSDATE + 1 + (23/24)
   AS SELECT * FROM wherever
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally NOT use the scheduler built into the mat view CREATE statement (next clause).  The main reason (for me) is that you cannot declare the refresh non-ATOMIC this way (at least I haven't found the syntax for this at CREATE time).  Depending on your refresh requirements and size, this can save A LOT of time.

Also, Oracle provides a very good scheduler that is independent of each individual object, and it is very easy to see what's scheduled/running at what time, makes changes, create complex job chains, view logs of past job runs, send email notifications, etc etc.

I would use **dbms_mview.[refresh](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_mview.htm)('MY_MATVIEW', 'C', atomic_refresh=>false)** in a dbms_scheduler job.  More work to setup, yes, but more flexible and powerful in the end.